# What is the difference between SHDeleteKey and RegDeleteTree?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

[RegDeleteTree](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/windows/desktop/aa379776(v=vs.85).aspx)

- Description: Deletes the subkeys and values of the specified key recursively.
- Signature: `LONG WINAPI RegDeleteTree(HKEY, LPCTSTR)`
- Minimum Supported: Vista
- Includes: `Winreg.h/Advapi32.lib`

[SHDeleteKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/windows/desktop/bb773486(v=vs.85).aspx)

- Description:  Deletes a subkey and all its descendants. This function removes the key and all the key's values from the registry.
- Signature: `LSTATUS SHDeleteKey (HKEY, LPCTSTR)`
- Minimum Supported: XP
- Includes: `Shlwapi.h/Shlwapi.lib`

It looks they are both used to remove registry recursively. And their parameters signatures are almost the same.

Is the `RegDeleteTree` just a refined version of `SHDeleteKey` with a different name? Should I change to use newer `RegDeleteTree` or are there some differences between them?

Comment: Did you mean to say `RegDeleteTree` everywhere you said `RegDeleteKeyEx` above? Because the MSDN page for the later explicitly says it is _not_ recursive, but the former is.

Comment: Thanks @Christian.K. How I met such big typo, ha. I've fixed that.

Comment: My guess would be RegDeleteTree was unavailable on Windows 9x and so the shell team wrote their own version.

Comment: [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2007/11/05/the-shell-used-to-get-all-the-cool-apis.aspx) blog post by Larry Osterman has some history on the subject. Other than that, I think the reason is just that: history.

Comment: @Christian.K It looks like the API is moved from shlwapi.lib for removing the shell library dependency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO, and the documentation provided, I think the differences are;

- API moved to different dll, the reason can be removing the shell library dependency for a single functionality as commented by OP.
- RegDeleteTree needs you to have KEY_SET_VALUE privilege if the key have any value.

Link given by Christian.K summarizes it well. I am including some of the significant part of that blog in the answer;

> Over the past couple of releases of Windows, there have been a great
>   number of "shell" helper APIs that have gotten "promoted" out of the
>   shell and transformed into Win32 core APIs.  One of the reasons for
>   that has been the ongoing Architectural Layering effort initiated by
>   some of the teams in the Core OS Division.
>
> The SHRegGetValue API was one of the APIs flagged by the layering
>   issue as being more appropriate for core OS functionality - the
>   analysis done by the layering team showed that a number of low level
>   components in operating system were calling into the shell DLLs
>   because the shell helper functions provided some convenient
>   functionality that wasn't present in the lower layers.
>
> As a result, a number of shell APIs were recreated as kernel32 APIs.

Answer (score 8):

The main differences between `SHDeleteKey` and `RegDeleteTree` are these:

1) The way they delete registry keys. For example:

```
SHDeleteKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"Software\\Company\\App\\Settings");
```

will delete everything in the `Settings` key, **including** the `Settings` key itself. While:

```
RegDeleteTree(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"Software\\Company\\App\\Settings");
```

will delete everything in the `Settings` key, **except** the `Settings` key. It will remain empty.

2) `RegDeleteTree` allows to specify WOW64 key redirection as such:

```
HKEY hKey = NULL;
if(RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
    L"Software\\Classes\\CLSID\\{-my-guid-}", 0, 
    DELETE | KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS | KEY_QUERY_VALUE | KEY_SET_VALUE |
    KEY_WOW64_64KEY, //For WOW64, delete only 64-bit redirected part
    &hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    if(RegDeleteTree(hKey, NULL) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        //Deleted everything in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{-my-guid-}
    }

    RegCloseKey(hKey);
}
```

3) `RegDeleteTree` resides in the same lower-level DLL as the rest of the registry functions, i.e. `Advapi32.dll`, while `SHDeleteKey` is in Windows Shell's `Shlwapi.dll`. This distinction may be important for certain types of services.

4) `RegDeleteTree` is not available on older operating systems, such as Windows XP SP3, Server 2003. It is only available since Vista and Server 2008.

Comment: Good answer, but (2) isn't strictly true - you can pass SHDeleteKey the handle of a key that you've opened using RegOpenKeyEx (thus allowing you to use the KEY_WOW64_64KEY flag)...

Comment: @Liam: OK, good point. I've never tried it like that to confirm though.